# How to stop Mac Mail 100% CPU?

Tags: mail.app

I'm running MacOS 10.15.3 on a Macbook Pro. Everyday for over a week now, Mac Mail hovers around 140% CPU. I restart Mail and it works fine until that evening or the next day.

I changed it to check mail every 5 minutes instead of Automatically but that didn't help. Besides reinstalling MacOS or removing/adding mail accounts, is there some way to resolve this?

Comment: assuming all of them are IMAP accounts, delete all & sign back in.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250776299 - will this help you?

Comment: @Udhy Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. This forces the fans of my MacBook to run at 150% and generate massive amounts of heat, more so than I'm comfortable working around. Does anyone have a fix for this yet? For me it seems to be a result of one of my share folders.

Comment: Still an issue on macOS 13.0.1 22A400.